# How to display shadows behind text?

Tags: nautilus

Is it possible to display shadows behind text on the gnome desktop just like in this picture?

[image]

Comment: In what software/program?

Comment: Edited. They are talking about the desktop (I hope) :P The original tags were: gnome desktop text shadow

Comment: I have shadows behind my icon text, but not in the same style; is this about getting the same style, rather than shadow?

Answer (score 1):

**No** , it's not easily possible yet.

It is a bug in Nautilus ( [Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/643836) and relevant [GNOME bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=317764) ).
The suggested fix is what you have requested here.

However, there is a patch in upstream Bugzilla bug which intends to fix this. It's not yet perfect, but if you want to use the shadow feature you can build nautilus with that patch.